# why Project directory could not be found, restart Next.js in your new directory error occurred during npm run dev command in frontside?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

After replacing the public and source folders of my project with those downloaded from Git, I created the `.env` file under my project with my client's Google token. I also used Tailwind CSS with Next.js, and the backend side is completely fine. However, after running the `npm run dev` command again, I encountered the following error: `Project directory could not be found, restart Next.js in your new directory.` You can see my file structure and the problem in the screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking so people can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same errors a few days ago, and as I search over it, it comes to be because of that experimental app directory feature. Try deleting it and use the file structure of NextJs, which is bug-free.

Comment: after delete app directory then  page 404 problem arises again and again what can I do more now